# Is a process kept in main memory while it is in the blocked/suspended state?

Tags: linux, memory-management, process

When a process P1 is in a blocked or suspended state, will the memory management system swap it out of main memory for room for an active process?

And if the process is determined to come back where is the Program's procedure call stack, Contents of program counter (PC) and Contents of program status word (PSW) stored? Does the OS keep it all in secondary memory or is *part* of the suspended/blocked process of P1 kept in main memory?

Comment: Recent Linux usually swap out some pages, not an entire process

Comment: IMHO blocked processes are handled in exactly the same way as others. Pages are offloaded if they are not used for a long time. In single-threaded process blocking will prevent memory access, so it will have higher chance to reach swap.

Comment: So I'm guessing when a process is swapped out of memory and put in a suspended state, all of its resident pages are moved out. When the process is resumed, all of the pages that were previously in main memory are returned to main memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I'm guessing when a process is swapped out of memory and put in a
>   suspended state, all of its resident pages are moved out. When the
>   process is resumed, all of the pages that were previously in main
>   memory are returned to main memory

Think in terms of pages, not processes.

Even an active process may have many pages evicted out of physical memory and into swap if the system is under memory pressure.

So, sure, a suspended process may have effectively all of its pages swapped out entirely.

But it is unlikely to have all pages swapped in simply because the process woke up.  Doing so would be a waste of CPU, I/O and memory.   Instead, pages will be brought back as needed (general case -- some pagers may bring back sets of pages heuristically).

---

If a process is active, then it won't be swapped out, so the dynamic state of the lowest call stack (all the register noise, red zone on stack, etc... ) isn't in play when the swap happens.

I.e. for a process to be swapped out the threads need to be blocked on something, typically a call into the kernel or into a system library that is blocking.  Registers will be out of play, etc...   Thus, the execution state that needs to be swapped out is pretty straightforward as the call return state will be preserved in the thread state itself (as the thread is blocked).

In fact, things like the PC and the PSW are preserved more as a part of the context switching subsystem than paging.   I.e. on a typical system, you'll likely have several hundred, maybe thousands, of threads running at once across the N physical cores of the CPU.   The concurrency support of the architecture is where you'll find how that state is maintained.